# How can I avoid peeling my hangnails?

Tags: personal-care

I have a tendency of biting skin around my finger nails that looks like it is going to come off. This skin sometimes looks like it wants to peel off, especially after doing manual work. I noticed that when I have a disturbing thought or when I am bored I put my finger between my teeth and cut my skin which then peels off leaving my finger with a wound.

Answer (score 4):

- If the skin is going to come off, it's definitely going to come off. Let it hold you for some more time. Forcing it to peel off definitely hurts the skin surrounding it. And also, biting our finger skin is unsafe as it may have numerous germs.
- Skin near our fingers are stressed when we do a lot of manual work, which partially blocks blood flow. One thing which helps me overcome biting skin near nails is to apply lubricants like oil or lotion.

I am a drummer and I face the situation quite often. Using oil or moisturising creams to keep the skin active is what I follow and it really helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try maintaining your skin too. Keep a 99 cent nail file on hand that you can use on callouses or rough skin near your cuticle. If you start picking, biting, etc. consciously smooth your skin with the file.

Comment: Using a nail file or emory board really does help. Clip the hang nail as close as you can with fingernail clippers, then do as djechlin suggests and smooth with a file or emory board. Put moisturizing lotion on afterwards to keep it from drying out, since the dried skin is easier to pick at.

Answer (score 2):

There are [foul-tasting materials](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000YUXI0) that can be applied to the nails to remind you to keep your hands from your mouth, or wear gloves.

Even if it's just while you're home alone, wearing of gloves is a reminder that will help you to break the habit. BTW, I had a similar issue, but after a hand injury required bandages for a week, my bad habit was broken.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep thinking about all of the gross germs that live on your fingers when you start to bite them. Unless you like being sick, you will probably want to stop.